Compiler prompt "[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]"
I compiled the following code using TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release (the one built into Bloodshed Dev-C++):
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAXN=1005;
int a[MAXN],b[MAXN],c[MAXN];

void input(int a[]){
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int len=s.length();
    for(int i=0;i<MAXN;i++) a[i]=0;
    for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i-=4){
        a[0]++;
        for(int j=max(0,i-3);j<=i;j++){
            a[a[0]] *= 10;
            a[a[0]] += s[j]-'0';
        }
    }
}

void output(int a[]){
    for(int i=a[0];i;i--){
        if(i==a[0])
            cout << a[i];
        else{
            int tmp=1000;
            for(int j=1;j<=4;j++){
                cout << a[i]/tmp%10;
                tmp /= 10;
            }
        }
    }
}

void add(int c[],int a[],int b[]){
    for(int i=0;i<MAXN;i++) c[i]=0;
    c[0]=max(a[0],b[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<=c[0];i++){
        if(i<=a[0]) c[i]+=a[i];
        if(i<=b[0]) c[i]+=b[i];
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=c[0];i++){
        c[i+1] += c[i]/10000;
        c[i] %= 10000;
    }
    while(c[c[0]+1]>0){
        c[0]++;
        c[c[0]+1] = c[c[0]]/10000;
        c[c[0]] %= 10000;
    }
}

int main(){
    int t,c=0;
    cin >> t;
    for(int r=0;r<t;t++){
        input(a);
        input(b);
        add(c,a,b);
        cout << "Case " << ++c << ":" << endl;
        output(a);
        cout << " + ";
        output(b);
        cout << " = ";
        output(c);
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Here's a piece of high-precision addition code written for this problem.
When I compile, the compiler reports the following error:

I am not aware of this error, how can I fix it please?

int a[MAXN],b[MAXN],c[MAXN]; -- int t,c=0; -- how can I fix it please? -- Stop using one-letter variable names.  Make the names of your variables descriptive of what they are to mean.

The int array c is shadowed by the int c declared at the beginning of main

GCC 4.9.2 -- Also, this is an ancient version of this compiler.  g++ is up to at least version 13.

As to the actual problem, there are more C++ idiomatic ways of solving it.  Start with this and improve on it, such as doing the column-by-column math without reversing the string.

Replace ALL your "C" style arrays with C++ style arrays. And or std::vector if you want them to be resizable. Also never use global variables, do NOT use #define to define constants, use static constexpr std::size_t MAXN = 1005; instead. Stop using using namespace std; Somehow it really looks like you learned C++ from the wrong source... where have you learned C++ from?

May I also recommend "visual studio community edition" to be your next development enironment (assuming you're not writing code professionally) that way you can use more modern versions of C++. And you actually have a chance to follow the C++ core guidelines

A [mre] (MRE) for a syntax error rarely requires so many lines of code. The error message tells you how to build up a MRE: The first error is in main(), and it occurs on a line that invokes add(). Fortunately, there is only one such line. So start your MRE with that one line in the main function: int main(){ add(c,a,b); }. Next, add the bare minimum number of lines needed to define the needed symbols. That is, void add(int c[],int a[],int b[]){} (with an empty body) and the definitions of the c, a, and b used within main. Then verify this reproduces the stated error.

@PepijnKramer As a matter of fact, I am a Chinese student who is preparing for NOI (National Youth Olympiad in Informatics). In my country, teachers make us use statements like const, using namespace std, and this doesn't seem to cause any real inconvenience, at least for now.

A lot of teachers (all over the world) are doing that (still teaching "C"). They learned C++ as it was 20 years ago and never updated their knowledge or training material afterwards. C++ is continously improving and I basically expect teachers to do the same. They really should be reading the C++ core guidelines, because when you follow those guidelines you can do more with less code and your code will contain less bugs

@GavinCQTD -- If you look at the solution I linked to, it is commented as to what is being done.  A lot of your code attempts to do the same thing, but with hand-written for loops, which makes the code error-prone and very hard to follow.   Also, note that everything is done using std::string.  There are no giant int arrays.   The point is that you have many parts of C++ that you are not aware of that would have made your code much easier, and these are the things you should strive to learn.

Also just to let you know, I was able to write that code on the first try, and it worked.  I didn't expect it to, but I had a plan as to how approach adding "big integers".  1) Reversing the strings allows a more natural loop from 0.  2) Making sure both numbers are the same size by adding 0's to the smaller number.  3) Doing a column by column addition, just like you would do in elementary school, along with a carry.  4) When done, making sure that the last carry (if it exists) is added to the result string.  5) Return the reversed result string.

To summarize and answer the main question, the int variable c declared locally in main shadows the declaration of the global int array also called c.
You're compiler is giving out an error because the expected parameter type is int[] aka int* (in C, arrays are simply passed by giving a pointer to the first element, and the size) but the type of the shadowing variable is int.
int main(){
    int t,c=0; //This variable shadows global array called c
    cin >> t;
    for(int r=0;r<t;t++){
        input(a);
        input(b);
        add(c,a,b);
        cout << "Case " << ++c << ":" << endl;
        output(a);
        cout << " + ";
        output(b);
        cout << " = ";
        output(c);
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

As other pointed out, in C++ you'd be better off using STL arrays. i.e replacing
const int MAXN = 1005;
int a[MAXN],b[MAXN],c[MAXN];

by
constexpr std::size_t MAXN = 1005;
std::array<int, MAXN> a, b, c;

(Same for function parameter types)
Also it would be good practice to avoid single letter variable names and give more descriptive names, this could avoid shadowing an already used letter :)
